# Keep component from unmounting on React Router v4 transition

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I transition (route) from a parent component to a child component. When I go Back to the parent, it re-mounts entirely, reloading data, and re-rendering.

How can I keep a specific component from unmounting [on a certain child route]?

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/44lgke/unmount_a_component_and_remount_it_later/

Comment: I have reviewed this a few times, and I just don't think it fully applies to my use-case. At the moment, I am using a state check, to see if data exists before trying to reload it. Thanks for the response and interesting link all the same.